# Netplan DNS disaster

Tags: networking, dns, netplan

I'm struggling to get netplan to work. (I thought I still wanted resolv.conf this does fix DNS but gets re-written on reboot.)
Everything appears to be correct but I can't ping.

```
$ sudo netplan --debug apply
** (generate:14256): DEBUG: 00:38:22.887: Processing input file /etc/netplan/50-cloud-init.yaml..
** (generate:14256): DEBUG: 00:38:22.888: starting new processing pass
** (generate:14256): DEBUG: 00:38:22.888: We have some netdefs, pass them through a final round of validation
** (generate:14256): DEBUG: 00:38:22.888: ens160: setting default backend to 1
** (generate:14256): DEBUG: 00:38:22.888: Configuration is valid
** (generate:14256): DEBUG: 00:38:22.888: Generating output files..
** (generate:14256): DEBUG: 00:38:22.888: NetworkManager: definition ens160 is not for us (backend 1)
DEBUG:netplan generated networkd configuration changed, restarting networkd
DEBUG:no netplan generated NM configuration exists
DEBUG:ens160 not found in {}
DEBUG:Merged config:
network:
  bonds: {}
  bridges: {}
  ethernets:
    ens160:
      critical: true
      dhcp4: true
      dhcp4-overrides:
        use-dns: false
      dhcp6: true
      dhcp6-overrides:
        use-dns: false
      ipv6-privacy: true
      nameservers:
        addresses:
        - 10.10.11.200
        - 1.1.1.1
        search:
        - home
  vlans: {}
  wifis: {}

DEBUG:Skipping non-physical interface: lo
DEBUG:device ens160 operstate is up, not changing
DEBUG:Skipping non-physical interface: docker0
DEBUG:Skipping non-physical interface: hassio
DEBUG:Skipping non-physical interface: vethecdde1c
DEBUG:{}
DEBUG:netplan triggering .link rules for lo
DEBUG:netplan triggering .link rules for ens160
DEBUG:netplan triggering .link rules for docker0
DEBUG:netplan triggering .link rules for hassio
DEBUG:netplan triggering .link rules for vethecdde1c
$ ping google.com
ping: google.com: Temporary failure in name resolution
```

edits per request.

I assumed I was using netplan since it was installed.

/etc/netplan/50-cloud-init.yaml I did not create this file it was there.

```
network:
    ethernets:
        ens160:
            critical: true
            dhcp4: true
            dhcp4-overrides:
                use-dns: false
            dhcp6: true
            dhcp6-overrides:
                use-dns: false
            ipv6-privacy: true
            nameservers:
                search: [home]
                addresses: [10.10.11.200, 1.1.1.1]

    version: 2
```

When I try to the two commands I get error for both.

```
$ sudo systemd-resolve --status
Failed to get global data: Unit dbus-org.freedesktop.resolve1.service not found.
$ sudo resolvectl --status
sudo: resolvectl: command not found
```

Comment: Are you using Netplan or NetworkManager?  This here sounds a lot like NetworkManager may be taking control.  Is this a Desktop or Server setup, and have you verified you aren't using any other network configuration manager like NetworkManager or otherwise to control the interfaces?  Can you provide a copy of your `/etc/netplan` configuration, not just the error output here?  Also the output of `systemd-resolve --status` or `resolvectl --status` depending on which Ubuntu you're on (20.04+ has `resolvectl`, 18.04 doesn't so you have to invoke via the `systemd-resolved` command)

Comment: @ThomasWard I added the info you requested.

Comment: $ sudo: resolvectl: command not found
What Ubuntu release are you running?  This command is part of systemd in 20.04 and later so should always be present.
$ sudo systemd-resolve --status
Why is systemd-resolved not running on your system? `systemctl status systemd-resolved`

Comment: version: 18.04.6

Answer (score 0):

What you want is Dnsmasq. Netplan only allows to configure fallback DNS, not a domain DNS.

### Prepare installation

- Remove "systemd-resolved"

  - `sudo systemctl disable systemd-resolved`
  - `sudo systemctl stop systemd-resolved`
- Remove linked resolv.conf

  - Make sure it is a link (will point to something like: ...systemd/resolve/stub-resolv.conf):
  - `sudo ls -lh /etc/resolv.conf`
  - Remove link:
  - `sudo rm /etc/resolv.conf`
- Add temporary DNS

  - `sudo echo "nameserver 8.8.8.8" > /etc/resolv.conf`
- Install Dnsmasq

  - `sudo apt update`
  - `sudo apt install dnsmasq`

### Problem with dnsmasq.d/lxd

You might get this error when `dnsmasq` starts initially:

> dnsmasq: cannot access /etc/dnsmasq.d/lxd: No such file or directory

To resolve this just remove symlink ¯\*(ツ)*/¯

```
sudo rm /etc/dnsmasq.d/lxd
```

And restart:

```
service dnsmasq restart
service dnsmasq status
```

### Configure DNSmasq

Edit `/etc/dnsmasq.conf`.

Search and uncomment this options:

- domain-needed
- bogus-priv
- strict-order
- no-resolv

Add your domain DNS servers e.g.:

```
server=/mycompany.com.pl/192.168.0.123
server=/some.vlan/10.234.0.123
```

Add generic servers e.g.:

```
server=1.1.1.1
server=8.8.4.4
```

Restart when done:

```
service dnsmasq restart
service dnsmasq status
```

Note that status will show which DNS servers are actually used (`using nameserver ...`).

### Final steps

- Set DNS to local:

  - Add local DNS in resolve:

    - `sudo echo "nameserver 127.0.0.1" > /etc/resolv.conf`
  - Update `/etc/netplan/` yaml file too.
- Test with `dig` (or `ping`).

  - (look for `;; ANSWER SECTION:`)
  - `dig app01.some.vlan`
  - `dig server.mycompany.com.pl`
- Enable running on boot:

  - `systemctl enable dnsmasq`